# Creating custom tab with ultimatemember plugin of wordpress

Tags: php, tabs, wordpress

I've been trying to create a custom tab for my website and am using UltimateMember plugin.

After bit of google I found some code snippet that can help me do it:

First we need to extend main profile tabs

```
add_filter('um_profile_tabs', 'add_custom_profile_tab', 1000 );
function add_custom_profile_tab( $tabs ) {

 $tabs['mycustomtab'] = array(
  'name' => 'My custom tab',
  'icon' => 'um-faicon-comments',
 );

 return $tabs;

}
```

Then we just have to add content to that tab using this action

```
add_action('um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default', 'um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default');
function um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default( $args ) {
 echo 'Hello world!';
}
```

But my question, to what file should I add this code to achieve what I need. It sounds very numb of me to ask this, but I'm seriously confused.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To your `functions.php` file?

Comment: @dingo_d tried that already. doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share my similar experience. First of all in this code :

```
$tabs['mycustomtab'] = array(
  'name' => 'My custom tab',
  'icon' => 'um-faicon-comments',
 );
```

You should use always

> mycustomtab

as key which I see you've already used. So that's true.
Generally it works out when you put this code in your active theme's functions.php
But if it doesn't work out, consider adding this to core file um-filters-misc.php in the plugin core file folder for ultimate-member. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: worked for me. had to add it to um-filters-misc.php file. Thanks. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still needs help on this, but make sure to add a 'custom' key/value like this:

```
$tabs['mycustomtab'] = array(
  'name' => 'My custom tab',
  'icon' => 'um-faicon-comments',
  'custom' => true // <- needs to be added so it shows up on the profile page
 );
```

The code example in the [UltimateMember documentation](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/64-extending-ultimate-member-profile-menu-using-hooks) -specifically for extending the Profile Menu using hooks- doesn't work because the sample code doesn't have that line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for your help... im using this codes and works "good"... if a want to put shotcode the website print "blue screen" error... [ultimatemember form_id="15817"] (if i use "hello word" works perfect..

```php
function um_mycustomtab_add_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['mycustomtab'] = array(
        'name' => 'Seguimiento',
        'icon' => 'um-faicon-pencil',
    );

    return $tabs;
}

add_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', 'um_mycustomtab_add_tab', 1000 );

// Action
function um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default( $args ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[ultimatemember form_id="15817"]'); //this not work
}

add_action( 'um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default', 'um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default');
```

[here some screenshots tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5TMX.png)